# Finite intersection property and compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I was going through the Lec 13 and Lec 14 of Harvey Mudd's intro to real analysis series where Prof Francis introduces Finite Intersection property(FIP) as

> $\{K_\alpha\}$ is a collection of compact subsets of a arbitrary metric space $X$. If any finite sub-collection have a non-empty intersection then the entire collection has a non-empty intersection

In the next lecture he introduced a theorem which relates compactness to a intersection of a collection closed set as follows

> $X$ is compact iff any collection of closed sets $\{D_\alpha\}$ (subsets of X) satisfies the FIP.

Now this theorem was a little confusing because FIP as introduced considers the collection to be of compact sets and not just closed, also the proof of FIP used compactness of the sets in the collection in it's proof.

I tried to search up the explanation/definition for FIP and came across a different definition which was

> A collection of nonempty subsets $\{A_i\}$ of $X$ is said to have the FIP iff every finite intersection of the sub-collection is non-empty.

So I'm a bit confused as to which one of these is the correct definition of FIP? And if the one given by Prof Francis is correct then how does it apply to the closed sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem, because you don’t have to use the compactness of the collection to prove the theorem.

In fact if $X$ is compact and if  $\{C_\alpha\}$ is a collection of closed sets with the FIP property, then by contradiction if $\cap C_\alpha= \emptyset$ then $\cup C_\alpha^c=X$ and so $\{C_\alpha^c\}$ is an open cover of $X$ that does not admits  a finite subcover. Thus $X$ cannot be compact.

You can prove the inverse one in a similar way.

Now the definition of FIP property is usually done with a collection of ‘sets’. The theorem holds also for only a collection of closed subsets and the definition of your book it makes sense because if $X$ is compact then each closed subset is also compact and so each collection of closed subsets of $X$ has to be a collection of compact subsets of $X$.

Comment: Actually the 1st quoted text was introduced as the definition of FIP, but I guess the one i mentioned in the end "A collection of nonempty subsets $\{A_i\}$ of X is said to have the FIP iff every finite intersection of the sub-collection is non-empty." seems to be the correct definition

Comment: @grey yea, exactly